# Running multiple SQL files in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have some SQL files which I can run in a single script in oracle like this:

```
start create_tst_prod_class_tbl.sql
start create_tst_tran_ins_type_tbl.sql
start create_tst_order_type_tbl.sql
start create_tst_timezone_tbl.sql
```

Now I want to do that in MSSQL too but I could not figure out how. I have tried following things:

1. Writing a query like this:

   ```
   :r  "C:\Users\Ferid\Desktop\standard\create_tst_prod_class_tbl.sql"
   :r  "C:\Users\Ferid\Desktop\standard\create_tst_tran_ins_type_tbl.sql"
   :r  "C:\Users\Ferid\Desktop\standard\create_tst_order_type_tbl.sql"
   :r  "C:\Users\Ferid\Desktop\standard\create_tst_timezone_tbl.sql"
   ```

   and activate SQLCMD mode but when I execute it this error occurs:

   ```
   A fatal scripting error occurred.
   Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing EXIT.
   ```
2. Creating a batch file in the folder where the SQL files are with this content:

   ```
   SET SQLCMD=sqlcmd -S<Servername> -d<databasename> -U<Username> -P<Password> -E
   for %%d in (*.sql) do %SQLCMD% -i%%d
   ```

   When I run it following error occurs:

   ```
   Sqlcmd: The -E and the -U/-P options are mutually exclusive.
   ```
3. Creating a batch file in the folder where the SQL files are with this content:

   ```
   for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S <servername> /d <databasename>
   -U <username> -P <password> -i"%%G" 
   pause
   ```

   When I run it following error occurs:

   ```
   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Named Pipes Provider: 
   Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. .
   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : A network-related
   or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
   Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if
   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
   For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
   ```

   Sadly I have no access to remote connections options.

Are there any other options or ways to fix these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case 2. is working:

```
SET SQLCMD=sqlcmd -S<Servername> -d<databasename> -E
for %%d in (*.sql) do %SQLCMD% -i%%d
```

OR

```
SET SQLCMD=sqlcmd -S<Servername> -d<databasename> -U<Username> -P<Password>
for %%d in (*.sql) do %SQLCMD% -i%%d
```

Comment: No, when I try it this error occurs: 
Sqlcmd: The -E and the -U/-P options are mutually exclusive.

Comment: error only together : -U<Username> -P<Password> -E

OK : -E (used your windows account)
OK : -U<Username> -P<Password> (used SQL account)

Comment: Note if using this just from a command line vs running in a batch file, the 2nd line will only have single % symbols so like this:  for %d in (*.sql) do %SQLCMD% -i%d

Answer (score 1):

In my local worked well as:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aK1L.png)

```
 for  %%f in (*.sql) do (
    sqlcmd -S <Servername> -U <Username> -P <Password> -d <databasename>  -i %%~f >> "%%~f.csv"
    )
```